# Tensorflow matrix multiplication error (Dimensions must be equal, but are 3 and 4 for 'Mul')

Tags: tensorflow, matrix-multiplication

I'm trying to build a basic setup:

An input of 4 values.
Then one layer of 3 neurons.
The formula is `a = W*x + b`.

In theory, `x` will be `4x1`, `W` will be `3x4` and `a` then will be `3x1`.

Now I'm trying to define this in tensorflow syntax:

```
import tensorflow as tf
sess = tf.Session()
W = tf.constant([
    [.2, .3, -.1, -.2],
    [.2, -.1, .7, -.1],
    [.1, .4, -.4, -.3],
], dtype=tf.float32)
print(w.get_shape()) # (3, 4)

x = tf.constant([
        [0.0],
        [1.0],
        [2.0],
        [3.0]
    ]
)
print(x.get_shape()) # (1, 4)

a = W*x

print(sess.run(a))
```

Then i get this error,

```
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError: 
Dimensions must be equal, but are 3 and 4 for 'Mul' (op: 'Mul') 
with input shapes: [3,4], [4,1].
```

I think this is a perfectly normal computation (`(m,n) X (n,k) = (m,k)`).
So, I expect a `(3,1)` for `a`.

What did I not get?

Comment: Please see the difference between `tf.matmul` and `tf.multiply`

Comment: that makes no difference (matmul, multiply, or `*`)

Comment: matmul is matrix multiplication, whereas the other two are element-wise. Did you try tf.matmul for your code above?

Comment: Yes, same same,

Comment: @dgumo i'm sorry, it works now with matmul. Seems I didn't test your suggestion properly. My apologies. I'll upvote.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was hoping that my comment above would get you the answer. But, hope the following helps:

The `*` or `tf.multiply` does element-wise multiplication. It needs the dimensions to match or be such that they can be broadcasted. Use `tf.matmul`

```
import tensorflow as tf
sess = tf.Session()
W = tf.constant([
    [.2, .3, -.1, -.2],
    [.2, -.1, .7, -.1],
    [.1, .4, -.4, -.3],
], dtype=tf.float32)
print(W.get_shape()) # (3, 4)

x = tf.constant([
        [0.0],
        [1.0],
        [2.0],
        [3.0]
    ]
)
print(x.get_shape()) # (1, 4)

a = tf.matmul(W,x)

print(sess.run(a))

print a.shape
```

Output:

```
(3, 4)
(4, 1)
[[-0.5       ]
 [ 1.        ]
 [-1.29999995]]
(3, 1)
```